# Loading order of viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter, android-adapter

Imagine there is a viewpager with 4 page, the 1st and 2nd page are storing the edittext, and the third one need to display the inputed data from 1st and 2nd page.

The problem is , viewpager pre-load the pervious page and next page , if I create the custom adapter like that:

**Custom adapter**

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        rootView = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(pages[position], null);

        if (position == 0) {
            form1(rootView);
        } else {
            form2(rootView);
        }

        ((ViewPager)container).addView(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }
```

**Example function form2**

```
private void form2(View rootView){
    TextView previous_page = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.previous_page);
    TextView next_page = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next_page);

    final EditText type = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_type);
    final EditText amount = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_amount);
    final Spinner period = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_period);
    final EditText name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    final EditText phone_no = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_phone_no);
    final EditText email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_email);

    previous_page.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            top_bar.setImageResource(R.drawable.form_1_header);
        }
    });

    next_page.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] input_list = {amount.getText().toString(),name.getText().toString(),phone_no.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString()};
            String invalid_msg = check_valid(input_list);
            if (invalid_msg.equals("")) {
                new FormHandler(ctx,formListener).execute(type.getText().toString(),amount.getText().toString(),period.getSelectedItem().toString(),name.getText().toString(),phone_no.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, invalid_msg ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then , for example if I enter the 1st page, it call the instantiateItem 2 times, the position are 0 and 1 , and it called the form1() and the form2(), which I expect only when I enter that page , it call the function of that page . e.g. At 1st page , run form1(), At 2nd page , run form2(). How to fix that? thanks.

Update (1):

It caused a problem, when I enter 2nd tab , it preload the 3rd tab, which call the form3(), so after I input the data in those edittext at 2nd tab, and go to the 3rd tab, it does not call form3() again, so the 3rd tab does not display enter data from 2nd tab (The view was preload and instantiate already)

Update (2):

The page is not a fragment , it is a layout and inflate at the adapter(named "rootview" and the pages array is:)

```
int[] pages = {R.layout.form_1,R.layout.form_2,R.layout.form_3,R.layout.form_4};
```

Update (3):

My whole viewpager

```
    private class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    public int[] pages;
    private LinearLayout rootView;

    public ViewPageAdapter(int[] _pages) {
        pages = _pages;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (LinearLayout) object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        rootView = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(
                pages[position], null);

        if (position == 0) {
            form1(rootView);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            form2(rootView);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            form3(rootView);
        } else if (position == 3) {
            form4(rootView);
        }

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pages.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ary you using fragments for pages ? if yes then execute form1 and form2 in fragments.

Comment: If you don't want `ViewPager` pre-loaded previous and next pages, just use `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` and set limit: `setOffscreenPageLimit(0)`

Comment: viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);  adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(pages);  viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);   Still the same, nothing changes. Thanks

Comment: have you tried  `viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener( new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
  @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {}}`

Comment: Why not using the `Fragment`s?

Comment: becuase the structure is based on Fragmenttabhost , there is a problem when I change the fragment of specific tab

Comment: @user782104 can you post your `adapter` code completely! and also your `MainActivity` where you set `tabs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the setPrimaryItem method in adapter. this method will give the current displaying object. This may help you.

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    if (mobject != object) {
      mObject=objet; //mObject is global variable in adapter
      //You can update your based on your logic like below 
      View view == (LinearLayout) object;
      form4(view);
    }
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Then , for example if I enter the 1st page, it call the instantiateItem 2 times, the position are 0 and 1 , and it called the form1() and the form2(), which I expect only when I enter that page , it call the function of that page . e.g. At 1st page , run form1(), At 2nd page , run form2(). How to fix that? thanks.

you can not fix that, because of giving better UX to user `setOffscreenPageLimit(0);` dose not work and the default value is always `1` which means it always preloads your next and previous page.

> so after I input the data in those edittext at 2nd tab, and go to the
>   3rd tab, it does not call form3() again, so the 3rd tab does not
>   display enter data from 2nd tab (The view was preload and instantiate
>   already)

you can save your data in `SharedPreferaces` and read them in `onResume` method of `tab3`. in this way you will get correct data from `tab2` and `tab1.`

Comment: `onResume` will not work - that gets called when the fragment is attached (that is, when page 2 is shown), rather than when it is brought into view.

Comment: @Adam S you must use `setUserVisibleHint` and `getUserVisibleHint()`